# How to add Vue.js to an existing ASP .NET Core 2.0 MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, vue.js, asp.net-core-mvc

Basically I want to add Vuejs (newest) to already existing ASP .NET Core 2.0 MVC project and then return `Views` from endpoints like `/test`, where those Views are using Vue scripts from `wwwroot/js`

So far I tried:

> dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
>
> dotnet new vue

But I'd really want to have an empty project, as minimal amount of "js-not-wrtten-by-me" in project.

Thanks in advance.

PS: If I want to create content dynamically, then using endpoints via Controller isn't proper way to do that?

Comment: https://sirwan.info/archive/2018/05/28/TypeScript-and-Vue.js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the new [Vue cli 3](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) to scaffold a project inside .NET core solution. You can, for instance, put it inside a **ClientApp** folder. You will see something like this also with .NET spa templates. Once created, change the output of the files to build files to the **wwwroot** folder. Once there, you reference those files in your **.cshtml** page and you're all done.

I was writing my own webpack configuration and set up before but the new Vue cli makes all this not really worth it anymore.

EDIT: For everyone building multi-page applications and not SPA's, you can also take a look at the following example.

GitHub: https://github.com/danijelh/aspnetcore-vue-typescript-template

Answer (score 0):

Use LibMan, download libraries similar to npm, but is written in C#.